# Elementary derivation of the Lagrange remainder

Tags: calculus

What's wrong with the following:

$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + \frac12 f''(a) (x-a)^2 + \frac16 f'''(a) (x-a)^3 + \ldots
$$
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a) + \frac12 f''(a) (x-a) + \frac16 f'''(a) (x-a)^2 + \ldots
$$
By MVT, the LHS is equal to $f'(c)$ for some $c$ in $[a, x]$.
$$
f'(c) = f'(a) + \frac12 f''(a) (x-a) + \frac16 f'''(a) (x-a)^2 + \ldots
$$
Do the same thing again:
$$
f''(c_2) =\frac{f'(c) - f'(a)}{x-a} = \frac12 f''(a) + \frac16 f'''(a) (x-a) + \ldots
$$
This would imply that 
$$
f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(c_2)(x-a)^2
$$
But the Lagrange remainder should have a coefficient of $\frac12$ here. So what went wrong?

Comment: $\displaystyle a < c < x\quad$ or $\displaystyle\quad x < c < a$. So, $\displaystyle c$ depends on $\displaystyle x$.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that c is in [a,x]. I'm not sure I understand your point.

Comment: When you evaluate the derivative, you have to take into account that $c$ isn't indepent of $x$. I guess it's somehow difficult to know the exact $c$ dependence on $x$.

Comment: The mean value theorem does not apply to ratio $(f'(c)-f'(a)) /(x-a) $ so you can't replace it by $f''(c_2)$. Taylor's theorem is proved by the use of same means (Rolle's theorem) as used in proof of Mean Value theorem, but that does not mean it can be derived using mean value theorem in a straightforward way.

Comment: Thank you Paramanand! That's certainly one mistake here.

Comment: Felix, which evaluation were you saying was an issue? In any case, Paramanand has found at least one fatal bug.